# Carregar codigo de acordo com dispositivo

Tags: javascript, jquery

O trecho abaixo é similar ao que tenho na pagina inicial do site:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div id="minhaClass">
        <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/texto-1/">texto 1</a>
       <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/texto-2/">texto 2</a>
        <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/texto-3/">texto 3</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Nesse codigo tem php e html, a minha duvida é sobre quais funções do jquery posso estudar para possibilitar imprimir esse trecho no código dependendo do tamanho do dispositivo (desktop, celular, etc) usado?

Sei que é possivel usar @media queries como referencia ao carregar, mas como capturo isso com o jquery, quais funções possibilitam isso

Comment: Como assim "imprimir esse trecho no código"? Quer que essa div só exista no código-fonte da página em um certo tipo de dispositivo? Não há Javascript no mundo que faça isso.

Comment: Agradeço resposta, mas acredito ser possivel, sobre imprimir acho que pode usar o `.append()`, depois de uma condicional que verifica o tamanho do dispositivo usado

Comment: A questão é como capturo o tamanho do dispositivo, ao carregar a página, pelo DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa de *jQuery*. Com Javascript puro você consegue acessar o [objeto `screen` da variável global `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Screen) e obter a resolução da tela, i.e.:

```
console.log('Minha resolução é ' + screen.width + 'x' + screen.height);
```

Note que isso é a resolução do dispositivo. A área realmente visível da sua página, com o navegador maximizado, será quase sempre um pouco menor.

Agora, lembre-se sempre:

- **Resolução não é tamanho.** Um tablet ou mesmo um celular *high end* podem ter a mesma resolução de um monitor antigo, em uma tela menor;
- **Nunca tente determinar o tipo do dispositivo pela resolução de sua tela.** Hoje existem ecrãs grandes que são sensíveis a toque, por exemplo, então você pode servir-lhes interfaces amigáveis. Caso deseje realmente segregar seu conteúdo por dispositivos diferentes, trate-os por capacidades, não por resolução (nem por *useragent*). Eu tenho algumas respostas mais elaboradas sobre o assunto em algumas perguntas anteriores:

[Identificar se o dispositivo é pc ou celular e utilizar um código diferente pra cada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/202619/1658)

[Executar javascript apenas quando acessar o site de um celular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/200514/1658)

[Como detectar um dispositivo móvel em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195182/1658)

Comment: `if (screen.width < 640 || screen.height < 480) {
    // sirva a versão pra celular
}...` Obrigada Renan, é exatamente isso

Answer (score 0):

Com Jquery tem como vc capturar o tamanho da viewport com o código:

`$( window ).width();` e `$( window ).height();`

Ainda não está muito claro o que você deseja fazer, mas creio q se vc utilizar esta forma para buscar a largura e a altura atual da sua viewport, vc possa fazer os calculos que deseja.

Comment: Usar jQuery para obter esses valores é como usar um tiro de escopeta para matar uma mosca. Além disso esse é o tamanho da janela, não a resolução do dispositivo.

Comment: Eu apenas respondi o q ele perguntou. Ele quis saber como capturar o tamanho por Jquery, E foi o q respondi. Tem milhares de maneiras de fazer isso, e tudo depende do que o usuário prefere. Eu particularmente prefiro utilizar frameworks com grids. Mas como não sei o q ele quer fazer, então passei o q ele pediu.

O código retorna o tamanho da janela que está sendo exibida, independente do tamanho do dispositivo, o que pode ser bastante útil em alguns casos. Ai depende dele.

Comment: @FernandoVR Agradeço pela sua resposta também, muito obrigada

Comment: Disponha @Gislef ^_^